# Javascript and target="_top"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I'm working with a legacy frames website that was just moved into an iFrame.

Assuming I have the following function:

```
<script language = "javascript">
  function myFunction(){
    <!-- no console.log in IE 7 (my required target browser) -->
    alert('sup, yo?'); 
  }
</script>
```

and the following hyperlink triggering the function:

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction();" target="_top">click me</a>
```

**before** the move into an iFrame this worked ok.  Once the website was moved into the iframe, clicking the link in IE (not FF or Chrome), I would get the ever-so-helpful error:

```
Line: 1
Object expected
```

Once I removed the `target="_top"` attribute the function would work, so I don't need help solving the problem, but my question is:

*What is IE doing with the target attribute when calling a javascript function to invoke this behavior? I don't have other versions of IE installed, is this current behavior in 8+ as well?*

Thanks.

Comment: IE7 most certainly has `console.log`, you just have to make sure you've actually opened the web developer window - I know right :/

Comment: You should not use `href="javascript:myFunction();"` to run JS. Either use `onclick` attribute or set handlers from JS (preferred). Then you don't have to worry about this problem

Comment: Maybe it's trying to find the `myFunction` function in the `_top` frame? `target` is deprecated anyway. Actually write what you mean, rather than depend on quirky behaviour.

Comment: I agree juan and I usually don't, like I said this is legacy that I didn't create. I'm just cleaning up some errors. I don't do this today.

Comment: @Frits, I didn't realize there was a console, lol. I'll be downloading it now...

Comment: @Travis there's no download, just press F12. This is the time to fix it, you should clean it up as I suggested, trying to understand the behavior of a hack is futile

Comment: I tried that, No love. 7.0.5730.13  I found this though: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: Sorry about that, IE8 was the first one to include the dev tools

Comment: I'd fix it if it wasn't a huge site with a lot of almost identical but not quite code all over.  The site will be getting an overhaul soon, now we're just trying to get it moved and they haven't given me a lot of time to clock on the project so find/replace all target="_top" is going to have to do for now.

Comment: @Travis I don't understand what is so hard, a simple solution is to use `onclick` instead, yes all the usages. You will waste a lot more time trying to figure out this unspecified behavior than just fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to try to understand the behavior. You're using a technique that is not well defined and is not used by developers nowadays.

Instead of `href="javascript:myFunction();`, just use `onclick="myFunction(); return false"` or even better, set the handler from JS like the following

```
<a href="pageForUsersWithoutJs.html" id="my-link" >click me</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
// This is old school, but works for all browsers, you should use a library instead
document.getElementById('my-link').onclick = function() {
    // Do your thing
    return false; // so the link isn't followed
};
</script>
```

Comment: I don't disagree that it is poor practice but I've inherited half a dozen legacy websites (10+ years old) so until they can be rebuilt or sunset, understanding has it's value. would you mind briefly elaborating on "set the handler from JS"?

Comment: Check existance of [`elm.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener). found? use it. Not found (IE<9)? use [`elm.attachEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener#Compatibility).

Comment: "you should use a library instead" I usually use jQuery, but thanks for the explanation.